# Woocommerce remove new order header image for admin emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the logo header image for all 'new order' emails that go to the admin. I found the HTML code in the email-header.php file, but if I delete it it'll affect the emails being sent to customers. I think I have to edit a file in the /includes/ folder (class-wc-emails.php perhaps), but I'm not sure a) how to target admin only emails, and b) if I'm supposed to edit anything the in /plugins/woocommerce/ folder. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We will do it by easy step.

First we have to open email-header.php file from 
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails

Go to the WooCommerce => Settings => Emails => New Order in Admin Panel
Copy Text from Email-Heading textbox.
For me it is “New customer order”.

Find belove code in "email-header.php" under  “template_header_image”

```
<?php
      if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
        echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '" /></p>';
        }
?>
```

Important Note:
Make sure in belove code “if condition - if( $email_heading != "New customer order")” comparison text is copy from Email-Heading textbox from woocommorce admin.

Replace above codefrom "email-header.php" by Belove code

```
<?php
     if( $email_heading != "New customer order"){
        if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
            echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '" /></p>';
        }
     }
```

?>

You can do the same for other emails if you want to as well just make sure all different email catergories Email-Heading distinct.